# How can I correctly use <s:action name="populate" executeResult="true"/>?

Tags: java, struts2

I have this jsp

```
<s:form action="saveOrUpdateProduct" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" validate="true" theme="css_xhtml ">
    <s:textfield name="product.productName" label="Name" required="true" requiredposition="left" labelposition="left"></s:textfield>
    <br>
    <s:textfield name="product.productPrice" label="Price" required="true" requiredposition="left" value="1.0" labelposition="left"></s:textfield>
    <br>
    <s:hidden name="product.available" value="true"></s:hidden>
    <s:textarea name="product.productDescription" label="Description" required="true" requiredposition="left" labelposition="left"></s:textarea>
    <br>
    <s:action name="populate" executeResult="true"/>
    <s:file name="userImage" label="Picture" required="true" requiredposition="left" labelposition="left"/>
    <br>
    <s:submit value="Add"></s:submit>
    <br>
    </div>
</s:form>
```

If the file uploaded isn't a picture i would like to return to the same page with an error message, but when i try this, it shows the same page without executing `<s:action name="populate">` that populates 2 `<s:select>`

I couldn't find an example that works. The example from Struts 2 documentation works for result `name="success"`, but not for `"input"`.

Comment: Perhaps you'd better shows us your mappings (relevant struts.xml)

You mean that when the jsp is rendered from the INPUT result the `<s:action />` produce no html code? Can you check (in your web logs, or from some log your "populate" action) that the action is really not invoked ? Perhaps some namespace problem ?

Comment: In any case, I have my doubts about this design, placing a `<s:action />` inside a form  (specially to populate two selects) smells a little bad to me. This is not normally what an action is supposed to do. And I wonder if this can be make to work right, in the INPUT scenario (even if it is called and the selects populated, the right behaviour would be to keep the user selected item...)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make your action implement [Preparable](http://struts.apache.org/2.1.6/struts2-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/Preparable.html). In the `prepare` method, populate the selects, rather than having an `<s:action>`